# How can you specify a namespace in a BizTalk expression shape?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, edi

How can you specify a namespace in a BizTalk expression shape?

We want to check if the message has the EDI.ErrorDescription context property, so using code in an expression shape like ...

```
EDI.ErrorDescription exists msgTest
```

which doesn't show any errors, but then on building the solution, the file0.cs throws an error because we a conflicting Company.Project.EDI namespace.

But I can't find anyway to disambiguate the statement in the expression shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your Company.Project.EDI namespace is colliding with the EDI namespace that BizTalk uses.

For testing purposes I would try to rename your Company.Project.EDI namespace to something like Company.Project.SomethingOtherThanEdi. This will make the two namespaces different and will most likely work for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I could I would, but changing the namespace isn't an option, so I really need to find some way to disambiguate the  use of EDI.ErrorDescription

Comment: Personally I don't know of any other ways to reference a property. Perhaps someone else knows of a way? Don't mean to point the finger, but keep in mind that it might always mean trouble when using a very global name for a project. There's always a good chance that it might be used in a library or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Orchestration Designer is very sensitive to namespace collisions.  So, yes, the two EDI namespace parts are colliding.

There is no way to specify a using or using alias either.

You have two options:

1. Change Company.Project.EDI (as noted)
2. Add a level of redirection through a helper class with a non-conflicting namespace.